# Не стандартный обьект в db.json

Tags: javascript, json, api, объекты, fetch

У меня есть условие что у меня в db.json должен быть такой обьект,с которым я потом буду уже работать.

```
{"distance": {"unit": "m", "value": 0.5}, "convert_to": "ft"}
```

Я хочу его записать в свой db.json и через json-server получать потом через fetch и обрабатывать.

Как правильно его записать,сколько скобок не ставил,форматировал всё равно ругается json-server что это не обьект.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такая ошибка.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю не так, и что сделать так чтобы я потом смог работать нормально.

Та же ошибка вылазит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуй вместо `convert_to`  сделать `convertTo`  .... И ради интереса `convert\_to `  или `convert\\_to `  :D

Comment: Не помогает к сожалению. Могу полностью видоизменять обьект,но что-бы суть осталась та же

Comment: а, понял, ему нужно вот такое: `"convert_to" : { "key" : value }`

Comment: https://github.com/typicode/json-server#getting-started json-server требует, чтобы корневые поля были или массивами или объектами, поскольку имена полей - это роуты, по которым будет обращаться рест